# column filtering in datatables is not working with column reodering

Tags: jquery, datatables

Iam using Datatables 1.10.2 . I was trying to use column re-odering with column filtering in datatatbles but column re-odering disabled the column filtering .  but it only works in compatible view of IE 10 . i need to use IE browser without compatible view . can anyone help . thanks in advance.
  this is my code :

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
         var table;
         // DataTable               
         table = $('#example').dataTable({
             "processing": true,
             stateSave: true,
             "deferRender": true, // to make the search fast         

             "dom": 'C<"clear">Rfltipr', // for column Re-odering and column visibilty.  

             "ajax": {
                 "url": "/my/example.so",
                 "type": "GET"
             },
             "columns": [{
                 "title": "name",
                 "data": "name",
                 "name": "name"
             }, {
                 "title": "addeddate",
                 "data": "addeddate",
                 "name": "added date"
             }]
         });
         table.columnFilter({
                 sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                 aoColumns: [{
                         type: "text"
                     }, {
                         type: "date-range",
                         bRegex: true,
                         bSmart: true
                     }
                 }
             ]
         }); $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd'; $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);

     $(function() {
         $("#dialog").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             show: {
                 effect: "blind",
                 duration: 1000
             },
             hide: {
                 effect: "explode",
                 duration: 1000
             }
         });
         $("#opener").click(function() {

             $("#dialog").dialog("open");




         });
     });
```

Comment: your code is almost incomprehensible to decrypt - please style it better :)

Comment: How exactly is it failing, and is there a particular error message that shows up in the console?

Comment: and also  state save is working only without compatibility view while filtering and other features are working with compatibility view. its so confusing , do I need to change version of .js file or datatable version ? or what ?

Comment: console error in IE 10 web developer tool console  SCRIPT5022: Unexpected literal at position 4 
jquery-ui.js, line 4938 character 6